# How to blur the background of an iframe popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

When i applied filter:blur to the container(id="vaaSaleAlertsContainer") the popup gets blurred instead of background content. I want to blur the background content when popup is displayed.

iframe popup and container structure code:

```
<div id="vaaSaleAlertsContainer" style="position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 100%; background: rgba(176, 224, 230, 0.6); z-index: 100; opacity: 1.0375; display: block;">
  <span style="font-size: 36px; color: black; float: right; z-index: 101; margin-right: 17.0%; cursor: pointer;">×</span>
  <iframe id="vaaSaleAlerts" style="width: 850px; height: 500px; margin-left: -437px; margin-top: -60px; display: block; opacity: 1.0325;" src="//www.surveymonkey.com/r/Preview/?sm=3dkHz6PiHV6N5bw4fN2TwF2duwIk0ODvH_2FxpTqAOvifV47DxfX8nBHCSvjDRF2gi"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't access anything inside  cross domain iframe due to *"same origin policy"*

Comment: I don't want to access anything within the iframe I just want to blur the background content while iframe is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this structure

```
<div class="">
    <div style="filter:blur(2px)">
        ALL YOUR CONTENT
    </div>
    <div >
        <iframe src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your iframe src should be a url from your own website

Answer (score 0):

**Using Javascript:**

```
document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].style.WebkitFilter = 'blur(4px)';
document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].style.filter= 'blur(4px)';
```

**Using CSS:**

```
.container.blur{
filter: 'blur(4px)';
-webkit-filter: 'blur(4px)';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `#vaaSaleAlertsContainer` contain only the popup? If yes you could use the [`backdrop-filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter) CSS property.

#### CSS:

```css
#vaaSaleAlertsContainer {
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```